# Flaw in logarithmic derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, proof-verification

I need to derivate the following expression:

$f(x)=log(3x-1)^5$

I used the chain rule obtaining:

$f´(x)=\frac{1}{(3x-1)^5ln(10)}[(3x-1)^5]´$

And applied the chain rule again:

$[(3x-1)^5]´=[3]5(3x-1)^4=15(3x-1)^4$

Therefore:

$f´(x)=\frac{1}{(3x-1)^5ln(10)}15(3x-1)^4=\frac{15(3x-1)^4}{(3x-1)^5ln(10)}$

I tried to check if this is right on Symbolab but had a different result. Where did I go wrong?

EDIT: [HERE](https://es.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cleft(log%E2%81%A1%5Cleft(3x-1%5Cright)%5E%7B5%7D%5Cright)%5E%7B'%7D) IS THE SYMBOLAB RESULT

Comment: What did Symbolab get?  There are various possibilities for the discrepancy:  They may have simplified the answer to ${15\over(3x-1)\ln10}$, they may have interpreted "log" as the natural log ("ln") instead of log base $10$, or they may have differentiated the fifth power of $\log(3x-1)$.

Comment: I just updated the result from Symbolab in the last part @BarryCipra

Comment: Symbolab has interpreted the power 5 applied to the entire expression, rather than just the argument of the log

Comment: Just to be clear: Is my answer correct? Even though Symbolab interpreted it incorrectly? @DhanviSreenivasan

Comment: @RafaelMartínez, your answer is OK, but it really ought to be simplified (as I mentioned in my first comment).  Also, to avoid ambiguity, you would do well to write the function as $\log((3x+1)^5)$.  The extra parentheses make it completely clear what you're taking the log of.